# Получение,чтение, апдейт данных из БД MySQL через Android

Tags: php, java, mysql, android-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно решить проблему.

Есть Android приложение, которое является клиентом удаленной базы данных MySQL, может как вносить, так и читать записи. Брал за образец статью - http://devcolibri.com/1548, но когда начал подгонять под свое приложение наткнулся на проблему, если выбрать из списка элементов, любой элемент, приложение падает, а в исходниках из статьи все работает, хотя парсер один и тот же.

В логах что-то непонятное:

```
05-22 13:28:09.972    1483-1486/ru.dip D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 78K, 11% free 4832K/5428K, paused 1ms+0ms, total 3ms
05-22 13:28:09.976    1483-1587/ru.dip D/All Date:﹕ {"success":1,"homes1":[{"ipoteka":"0","price":"0","floor":"low","floors":"0","ownerphone":"0","street":"Street Three","owner":"","number":"","pid":"9","typehome":"brick","square":"0","photo":"20150522_023459_","rooms":"1"},{"ipoteka":"0","price":"0","floor":"low","floors":"0","ownerphone":"0","street":"Street Two","owner":"dfsdgdfg","number":"","pid":"10","typehome":"brick","square":"0","photo":"20150522_023519_","rooms":"1"},{"ipoteka":"0","price":"0","floor":"low","floors":"0","ownerphone":"0","street":"Street One","owner":"","number":"","pid":"11","typehome":"brick","square":"0","photo":"20150522_023536_","rooms":"1"},{"ipoteka":"0","price":"0","floor":"low","floors":"0","ownerphone":"0","street":"Street One","owner":"ddfgdf","number":"","pid":"12","typehome":"brick","square":"0","photo":"20150522_054641_","rooms":"1"},{"ipoteka":"0","price":"0","floor":"low","floors":"0","ownerphone":"0","street":"Street One","owner":"?????\n","number":"","pid":"13","typehome":"brick","square":"0","photo":"20150522_155145_","rooms":"1"},{"ipoteka":"0","price":"0","floor":"low","floors":"0","ownerphone":"0","street":"Street ???","owner":"","number":"","pid":"14","typehome":"brick","square":"0","photo":"20150522_103328_","rooms":"1"},{"ipoteka":"0","price":"0","floor":"low","floors":"0","ownerphone":"0","street":"Street One","owner":"","number":"","pid":"15","typehome":"brick","square":"0","photo":"20150522_105152_","rooms":"1"},{"ipoteka":"0","price":"0","floor":"low","floors":"0","ownerphone":"0","street":"Street ???","owner":"","number":"","pid":"16","typehome":"brick","square":"0","photo":"20150522_111034_","rooms":"1"}]}
05-22 13:28:15.260    1483-1483/ru.dip W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-22 13:28:15.284    1483-1483/ru.dip W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-22 13:28:15.284    1483-1483/ru.dip D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-22 13:28:15.284    1483-1483/ru.dip W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6128908)
05-22 13:28:15.288    1483-1486/ru.dip D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 145K, 12% free 5074K/5736K, paused 2ms+1ms, total 4ms
05-22 13:28:15.288    1483-1483/ru.dip E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
            at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at ru.dip.parser.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:70)
            at ru.dip.EditProductActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditProductActivity.java:137)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Класс Активити для отображения всех записей

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;



import ru.dip.parser.JSONParser;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AllList extends ListActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;


// Создаем JSON парсер
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DataList;

// url получения списка всех продуктов
private static String url_all_data = "http://192.168.1.39/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "homes1";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_STREET = "street";

// тут будет хранится список данных
JSONArray data = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_list);


    // Hashmap for ListView
    DataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Загружаем прожукты в фоновом потоке
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // получаем ListView
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // на выбор одного продукта
    // запускается Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Запускаем новый intent который покажет нам Activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EditProductActivity.class);
            // отправляем pid в следующий activity

            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // запуская новый Activity ожидаем ответ обратно
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}
// Ответ из Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // если результующий код равен 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // если полученный код результата равен 100
        // значит пользователь редактирует или удалил продукт
        // тогда мы перезагружаем этот экран
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Фоновый Async Task для загрузки всех продуктов по HTTP запросу
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Перед началом фонового потока Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllList.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Загрузка данных. Подождите...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Получаем все продукт из url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Будет хранить параметры
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // получаем JSON строк с URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_data, "GET", params);

        Log.d("All Date: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Получаем SUCCESS тег для проверки статуса ответа сервера
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // продукт найден
                // Получаем масив из Продуктов
                data = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

                // перебор всех продуктов
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Сохраняем каждый json елемент в переменную
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String street = c.getString(TAG_STREET);

                    // Создаем новый HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // добавляем каждый елемент в HashMap ключ => значение
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_STREET, street);

                    // добавляем HashList в ArrayList
                    DataList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // продукт не найденadmin
                // Запускаем Add New Product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        CreateActivity.class);
                // Закрытие всех предыдущие activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем прогрес диалог
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // закрываем прогресс диалог после получение все продуктов
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // обновляем UI форму в фоновом потоке
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Обновляем распарсенные JSON данные в ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllList.this, DataList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                        TAG_STREET},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // обновляем listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}

}
```

Активити которое читает выбранный элемент EditProductActivity.class - проблемный:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import ru.dip.parser.JSONParser;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

EditText inputStreetE;
EditText inputNumberE;
EditText inputRoomsE;
EditText inputSquareE;
EditText inputFloorsE;
EditText inputFloorE;
EditText inputTypeHomeE;
String inputIpotekaE; /// AHTUNG CheckBox
EditText inputPriceE;
EditText inputOwnerE;
EditText inputPhoneOwnerE;
String inputPhotoE;

Button btnSave;

String pid;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// url для получения одного продукта
private static final String url_product_detials = "http://192.168.1.39/get_product_details.php";

// url для обновления продукта
private static final String url_update_product = "http://192.168.1.39/update_product.php";

 // JSON параметры
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_HOMES1 = "homes1";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_STREET = "street";
private static final String TAG_NUMBER = "number";
private static final String TAG_ROOMS = "rooms";
private static final String TAG_SQUARE = "square";
private static final String TAG_FLOORS = "floors";
private static final String TAG_FLOOR = "floor";
private static final String TAG_TYPEHOME = "typehome";
private static final String TAG_IPOTEKA = "ipoteka";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_OWNER = "owner";
private static final String TAG_OWNERPHONE = "ownerphone";
private static final String TAG_PHOTO = "photo";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addE);

         // показываем форму про детальную информацию о продукте
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // получаем id продукта (pid) с формы
    pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

    // Получение полной информации о продукте в фоновом потоке
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // обрабочик на кнопку сохранение продукта
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // запускаем выполнение задачи на обновление продукта
            new SaveProductDetails().execute();
        }
    });



}

/**
 * Фоновая асинхронная задача для получения полной информации о продукте
 **/
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Перед началом показать в фоновом потоке прогресс диалог
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Получение детальнойadmin информации о продукте в фоновом режиме
     **/
    protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {

        // обновляем UI форму
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // проверяем статус success тега
                int success;
                try {
                    // Список параметров
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // получаем продукт по HTTP запросу
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // Успешно получинна детальная информация о продукте
                        JSONArray homes1Obj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_HOMES1);

                        // получаем первый обьект с JSON Array
                        JSONObject homes1 = homes1Obj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // продукт с pid найден
                        // Edit Text
                        inputStreetE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.streetE);
                        inputNumberE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HomenumbE);
                        inputRoomsE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.RoomsE);
                        inputSquareE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.squareE);
                        inputFloorsE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.floorsE);
                        inputFloorE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FloorE);
                        inputTypeHomeE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.typehomeE);
                        inputIpotekaE = "0";
                        inputPriceE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.priceE);
                        inputOwnerE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.OwnerE);
                        inputPhoneOwnerE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.OwnerPhoneE);
                                                    // покаываем данные о продукте в EditText




                        inputStreetE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_STREET));
                        inputNumberE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_NUMBER));
                        inputRoomsE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_ROOMS));
                        inputSquareE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_SQUARE));
                        inputFloorsE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_FLOORS));
                        inputFloorE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_FLOOR));
                        inputTypeHomeE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_TYPEHOME));
                        inputPriceE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                        inputOwnerE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_OWNER));

                        inputPhoneOwnerE.setText(homes1.getString(TAG_OWNERPHONE));


                    }else{
                        // продукт с pid не найден
                        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
                        pDialog.setMessage("Шеф, все пропало!");
                        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                        pDialog.show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем диалог прогресс
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // закрываем диалог прогресс
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

/**
 * В фоновом режиме выполняем асинхроную задачу на сохранение продукта
 **/
class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Перед началом показываем в фоновом потоке прогрксс диалог
     **/
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Сохраняем продукт
     **/
    protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {

        // получаем обновленные данные с EditTexts
        String street = inputStreetE.getText().toString();
        String number = inputNumberE.getText().toString();
        String rooms = inputRoomsE.getText().toString();
        String square = inputSquareE.getText().toString();
        String floors = inputFloorsE.getText().toString();
        String floor = inputFloorE.getText().toString();
        String typehome = inputTypeHomeE.getText().toString();
        String ipoteka = "0";
        String price = inputPriceE.getText().toString();
        String owner = inputOwnerE.getText().toString();
        String ownerphone = inputPhoneOwnerE.getText().toString();
        String photo = "upd";

        // формируем параметры
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_STREET, street));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NUMBER, number));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ROOMS, rooms));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_SQUARE, square));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_FLOORS, floors));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_FLOOR, floor));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TYPEHOME, typehome));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_IPOTEKA, ipoteka));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_OWNER, owner));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_OWNERPHONE, ownerphone));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PHOTO, photo));

        // отправляем измененные данные через http запрос
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product, "POST", params);

        // проверяем json success тег
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // продукт удачно обнавлён
                Intent i = getIntent();
                // отправляем результирующий код 100 чтобы сообщить об обновлении продукта
                setResult(100, i);
                finish();
            } else {
                // продукт не обновлен
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * После окончания закрываем прогресс диалог
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // закрываем прогресс диалог
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}





}
```

JSODParser

```
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // метод получение json объекта по url
    // используя HTTP запрос и методы POST или GET
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Создаем HTTP запрос
        try {

            // проверяем метод HTTP запроса
            if(method == "POST"){

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
                HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(httpParams, "UTF-8");
                httpParams.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);





                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // пытаемся распарсить строку в JSON объект
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // возвращаем JSON строку
        return jObj;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас стандартный **NetworkOnMainThreadException**.

Заглянув в **гугл** можно узнать, что он возникает когда вы пытаетесь работать с сетью в главном (**UI**) потоке. Так нельзя с **API>=14**.

Вам надо вынести всю работу с сетью в отдельный поток. Например, используя, **AsyncTask**.

Comment: Так у меня все обращения к классу JSONParser реализуются через AsyncTask. Только везде все нормально проходит, а именно в окне чтения данных он ругается, хотя там тоже что GetProductDetails, что SaveProductDetails реализуются в AsyncTask.

Comment: Так у вас же в GetProductDetails сразу же идёт runOnUiTread, в коем http запрос чрез объект json. А так нельзя, о чём и говорят ошибка и мой ответ.

Comment: Простите меня, я еще слишком мало знаю про Android, а тут получается необходимо в AsyncTask избавиться от runOnUiThread, но как бы я его не удалял у меня весь код падает, не могли бы подсказать как правильно реализовать...

Comment: Вам нужно вынести логику работы с разметкой вынести в onPostExecute. Т.е. снача в doInBackground получаете данные, а потом, передав их в onPostExecute,  обновляйте текстовые поля